# SpriteKit texture atlases without including in bundle

Tags: sprite-kit

I see that SpriteKit expects its texture atlases to be within the application bundle. However I am downloading game assets over the internet. Is there a way to load the asset bundle from memory or through another method that allows this?

I already create SKTexture instances from assets downloaded over the internet, but I would love to get the performance boost from using atlases.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.
You can roll your own spritesheets but you can't use the built in functionality for an atlas that isn't in the bundle.
I solved this problem by downloading all of my non-atlas assets after install but shipping with all of the atlases to keep the IPA under 100MB.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that I can create atlases with a package like Texture Packer and then load an SKTexture for the atlas itself, and then while parsing the atlas info, create SKTextures for each entry using the textureWithRect:rect inTexture:textureAtlas method. Just got this working this evening and success. Have support from trimmed textures within the atlas, but not yet for rotated ones.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9 support [On Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=214), which might supply the functionality you are looking for. The primary purpose of this technology (part of [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)) is to reduce the bundle size when installing the app.